# How many pulses are required to charge the capacitor to 20V?

Tags: capacitor

A series of current pulses of 10mA amplitude and 2ms duration are applied to an initially-uncharged, 5 uF capacitor. How many pulses are required to charge the capacitor to 20V?

I thought of this formula:

\$V(t) = 1/C \int\limits_0^{t}idt + v_0\$

\$V(t) = \cfrac{1}{5 * 10^{-6}} \int\limits_0^{2 * 10^{-3}} 10 * 10^{-3}dt + 20\$

\$V(t) = 24 V \$

But then what? Note: The answer is 5 pulses.

Comment: Correction: `v0` is zero volts, since the cap is initially uncharged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between charge, Q, voltage, V, and capacitance, C, is

\$ C = \frac{Q}{V} \$

To charge your \$ 5 \mu F\$ capacitor to 20 V you will need a charge of

\$ Q = C \cdot V = 5 \mu F \cdot 20 V = 0.0001 C \$

Current is defined as \$ Amps = \frac{Coulombs}{Seconds} \$, meaning that each of the pulses delivers a charge of

\$ Coulombs = Amps \cdot Seconds = 10 mA \cdot 2 ms = 0.00002 \frac{C}{pulse} \$

Thus we will need the following number of pulses

\$ n = \frac{0.0001 C}{0.00002 \frac{C}{pulse}} = 5 pulses \$